# how to display popup on same screen with image on click of edittext

Tags: android

I have an edittext,my requirement is when i click on edittext a popup is come with only image on same screen at the same time user can input the value in edittext.
i am new to android,is this possible with QuickAction

[image: popup window like this image] 
what is other scenario to achive this.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: means after enter value in edittext pop up dismissed?

Comment: Just an easier way might be to use a spinner to choose the value and in an image you can show what each value means.

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal yes after enter the value or click on somwhere else popup dismissed..

Comment: You have to dismiss your Popup onTextChanged listner method of Edittext

Comment: @ShobhitPuri i don't know much about spinner ...could  you clerify how to use spinner in this situation or give me some good link...

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal but how to show popup.....